# How to update all the rows against each id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have a scenario where I have three tables.

> Users (`id_user`, `email`...)
>
> Logins (`id_login`, `email` ...)
>
> Campaigns (`id_campaign`, `id_user`, `id_login`)

Some of the users were migrated from table Users to Logins. The campaign table is added with a new field `id_login` now, which is empty. I want to update the campaign table (`id_login`) field with new id's those same users have got now in Logins table. email is unique of course which can be used in join but I don't know how to do that?

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume now that the Campaign table with only user IDs has to be updated with the Login IDs as well.

You could try this:

```
update Campaigns c
set id_login=(
       select id_login from Logins 
       where email like (select email from Users where id_user = c.id_user )
      )
where id_user > 0
```

Comment: but there is no email in the campaign table (c.email). Did I get this wrong or is it a mistake? Also, could you tell me why the use of (where not exists) i didn't get the part either. Thank you.

Comment: @Shaonline Yes it was a mistake. Have corrected both of them. I had earlier assumed 'migrated' meant deleted from the original table as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    update Campaigns b
set id_login=(
       select id_login from Logins
       where not exists (select * from Users where email like b.email)
      ); ------
```